# ArcGIS Javascript API Global Variable Issue

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to return a string when I click on a country in a map. The string is the country name, which will then be passed to a geoprocessing tool. I've definied "country" as a global variable. I'm trying to define it inside the click function and it's not working. console.log() doesn't print anything.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var country = {};
map.on("click", function(evt) {
  var selectQuery = new Query();    
  selectQuery.returnGeometry = true; 
  selectQuery.geometry = geometry;
  featureLayer.selectFeatures(selectQuery, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function(results) {
    country = results[0].attributes["NAME"];  
    console.log(country);           
  });
  map.infoWindow.setContent(content);
});
```

Comment: Does var country need to be an object? What is returned by the selection?

Comment: It needs to be a global variable so I can pass it from one function to another.  results[0].attributes["NAME"] is supposed to return the name of the country that's been clicked, since FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW returns an array of graphics, not strings. I don't think it's returning anything though, because nothing is being logged to the console when I click a country.

Comment: Right, so why not just use var country;

Comment: I've tried that. Won't it stay an empty variable once it's out of the scope of the functions?

Comment: It should not.  All scripts and functions should be able to access and modify it.

Comment: Well, I tried it and it's still not working. I'm still not sure that the callback function(results) is returning anything.

Comment: It's also logging an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: geometry is not defined

Comment: the geometry variable in selectQuery.geometry = geometry; is undefined

Comment: I'm confused as to how to define it. I tried countriesLayer.geometry, but that screwed everything up.

Comment: I renamed my function from evt to geometry, follwing this example https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/fl_selectfeatures.html Now I get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'wkid' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution. I needed to set the content after defining the link.

```
map.on("click", function uponClick(evt){

      identifyParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
      identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;
      identifyTask.execute(identifyParams, function(result) { 
         for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
            country = result[i].feature.attributes["NAME"];
         } 


            var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate();
           map.infoWindow.setTitle(country);
           map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint,   
           map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.mapPoint))

           var link = domConstruct.create("a",{
            "class": "action", 
            "id": "reportLink",
            "innerHTML": "Generate Report",
            "href": "javascript: void(0);"
          }, query(".actionList", map.infoWindow.domNode)[0]);

          map.infoWindow.setContent(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should listen to the click event of your featureLayer instead of the map, so you can access the attributes of the feature.
something like :

```
var country = ''; //"{}" means object but you want a string
On(featureLayer, 'click', function (e) {
  country = e.graphic.attributes.name;
});
```

Add "dojo/on" as a parameter of require, ie :

```
require([..., "dojo/on", ...], function (..., On, ...)
```

here is a code i posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/42419932/1851595

Comment: OK. I tried this and got the same results. Country is "undefined" if it's set as a string, and "object" if it's set as an object.                                 var country = '';
    
    on(countriesLayer, 'click', function (e) {
    var content = "<b>Location: </b> ${NAME}";
    var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Forecast Reports", content); 
    country = e.graphic.attributes.name;
    console.log(country);
    map.infoWindow.setContent(content);
    });

Comment: I need country to be global, so I can retrieve it from a click event. A link is created in the info window to a GP tool. Country needs to be passed into that when the link is clicked. I've tried a totally different approach with making the layer dynamic and using an identify task, and I'm able to return country, but I can't get the GP tool link into the popup.

Comment: Sorry but what you want is not clear.
You first asked to get the country name in a string, when you click on it.
Now, you want the country name to be in link which is in an info window ?
And you want a link to the GP tool in the info window ?

Comment: The name is showing up in the info window, that's never been a problem. I just need the name passed out as a string to the GP tool. I have a link to the GP tool in the popup, but it kept erroring out when I was trying to pass in the country string from a global variable. The initial click which pulls the country name and sets up the infotemplate and the GP tool itself are two different functions, which is why I needed it to be global.

Comment: But I've scrapped that approach and changed to a dynamic layer and used an identify task. This passes the country name string just fine. I've also tried to nest the GP tool link function into the initial click function, but the link is not showing up in the infowindow. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: you would not need to pass the global var in infoTemplate, just use `${NAME}` and in the click event function, you should fire the GP tool function with either the local string var country [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xc96ru5x/2/)

Comment: That's what I'm doing for the infoTemplate display. The problem now is, that the GP tool link is not being created in the infoWindow now that the entire process is nested under the initial click function. This is directly below map.infoWindow.show();                                                                      var link = domConstruct.create("a",{
                "class": "action", 
                "id": "reportLink",
                "innerHTML": "Forecast Report",
                "href": "javascript: void(0);"
              }, query(".actionList", map.infoWindow.domNode)[0]);

Comment: When I set map.infoWindow.setContent(country + link); I get "Brazil javascript: void(0);" in the infoWindow.

Comment: So, you want to build a link inside the infoTemplate ? Take a look at my demo, I posted the link at the end of my previous comment. Anyway, here it is again : https://jsfiddle.net/xc96ru5x/2/

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out, though.

Comment: I can't comment your answer below, so I'll post here. Glad you made it :) I've updated the jsfiddle according to your answer : https://jsfiddle.net/xc96ru5x/3/ you might take a look